# Laravel 5 error when update/install intervention/image

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

I tried to install intervention/image class via composer from [image intervention homepage](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) installation but it's ended with below error:

```
F:\Laravel\ecommerce>composer require intervention/image
Using version ~2.1 for intervention/image
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompil
  ePath()



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned wi
th an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:



require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update]
[--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-
packages] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Tried to research the same errors but did not found any. What's the problem here? and how to fix this :) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug when upgrading the Laravel version.

Deleting the `vendor/compiled.php` will fix this issue.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thnx